# How to add body background which sticks to container div?

Tags: background, containers

I have a container in the center of window. And my logo goes out from container to the left. I split my logo in 2 pieces. Right piece i added in my container with no-repeat. And left piece i have to add in my body background and somehow stick it to containers div.

i have drawn my issue: [image]

how to manage that issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it somehow different. You can always set background of `#logoimage` div to your logo with gradient, or simply put an image inside. One image is enough with full logo object.

style:

```
#container{
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#abc;
    position:relative;
}

#logoimage{
    display:block;
    width:170px;
    height:80px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#aaa;
    position:absolute;
    left:-70px;
    top:30px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container"><div id="logoimage"></div></div>
```

[live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/515qLez0/)

What's the most important of this is:

`position:relative` style of container element

`position:absolute` style of logo element

The idea generally is that in position absolute, you can set x,y relatively to element with position relative.

Comment: Thanks :) it helped :)